# Hosting Laravel in Cpanel doesn't run application

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I have problem when I'm trying to access home routes on website, but it seems that it doesn't pass form  **index.php**

dir of **require** and **$app** are work because when I **dd(1);** after it, it show result in website

```
require __DIR__.'/system/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/system/bootstrap/app.php';

dd(1);
```

but , the problem when handling  the incoming request in kernel , which means run application in same file (index.php)

[image]
the error after sending response

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not mess with those files. Seems that you havent defined the document root from the application.

Make sure that the document root is set to the folder `public/` inside the project folder.

Comment: I did not do anything to those file expect editing on require , $app direction , maybe because I use firebase not mysql ?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution ,

I should use base URL as "/" not "/FolderProject"

```
  pathInfo: "/"
  requestUri: "/"
  baseUrl: ""
  basePath: ""
```